# FFMPEG Scale video without filtering

Tags: ffmpeg

I am interested in scaling a video to a larger size without applying any filter or anything.  The output video should look very pixelated.  How do I do this in FFMPEG?

On the suggestion of Ronald S. Bultje, I am using the neighbor flag.  I have also decided to use the rawvideo codec to avoid compression.

The current command I am running is

```
ffmpeg -i vid.avi -s 800x800 -sws_flags neighbor -sws_dither none -vcodec rawvideo vid2.avi
```

The command line output of that command is

```
ffmpeg version 2.7 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-lzma --enable-gnutls --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --disable-indev=jack --disable-outdev=xv --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --enable-vda --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'vid.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:25.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 226 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, pal8, 80x80, 206 kb/s, 4 fps, 4 tbr, 4 tbn, 4 tbc
File 'vid2.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, avi, to 'vid2.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, pal8, 800x800, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 4 fps, 4 tbn, 4 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 rawvideo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  100 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=   62608kB time=00:00:25.00 bitrate=20515.4kbits/s    
video:62600kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.012614%
```

Comment: terminology: scale itself is a filter... so your request is a bit confusing

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i infile -vf scale=WIDTH:HEIGHT:flags=neighbor outfile
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i infile -s WIDTHxHEIGHT -sws_flags neighbor outfile
```

The critical part here is `flags` or `-sws_flags`, which selects the filter (and other scaling-related flags). The default filter value is bicublin (IIRC), which means a [bicubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) luma and [bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) chroma filter. [Nearest-neighbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) will do what you're asking for.

See [scaler options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html#scaler_005foptions) for a list other scaling algorithms.

Comment: this is closer but still not exactly right.  The blown-up "pixels" are still not uniform.. There is some banding, and they are not all the same size, as if there was some compression done

Comment: Well obviously, because you can't have half-pixels. Look, let's say you have a 2x2 image and you're trying to create a 3x3 image from that. You can either do "nearest-neighbour" scaling, where the middle pixels (rows/columns) will have the value of either one of their neighbours (depending on how you round) and the edge pixels will have original edge values; or, you can apply some filter and give the middle pixels some value (mathematically) derived (filtered) from the edge pixels. You can't give half of the pixel one value and half of the pixel another value, a pixel can only have one value.

Comment: i'm scaling from 80x80 to 800x800 so there shouldn't be a problem with that.  I did partially solve this problem by using `-vcodec rawvideo` option, but now there is dithering noise that i can't get rid of with the `-sws_dither none` option.

Comment: My current command is `ffmpeg -i vid.avi -s 800x800 -sws_flags neighbor -sws_dither none -vcodec rawvideo vid2.avi`

Comment: Can you list the complete output of that command? I'm wondering if it converts pixelformat or something silly like that...

Comment: Try adding a particular -pix_fmt, e.g. -pix_fmt rgb24 or -pix_fmt yuv420p (after -sws_flags neighbor).

Answer (score 1):

You can reach your goal by scaling-down, and then scaling-up like:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf scale=iw/4:ih/4,scale=4*iw:4*ih:flags=neighbor out.mp4
```

The scale-factor of **4** can be modified to suit your needs.